# linking to home page Django

Tags: html, django

Im having problems with making a link to homepage. What i have right now is

```
href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
```

but obvioulsy its not effective. Im not using {% url 'index' %} because i cant type anything after it, e.g:

```
"{% url 'index' %}/articles"
```

Is there any way to do that, using url 'index' or any other way? I dont want to use django admin and database for that tho, as the database will not be saved, as im giving the code to someone else (but that doesnt really matter, just know that the database will not be saved and i cant do anything about it).

Comment: You can type anything after `{% url 'index' %}`. The tag will return a normal string after rendering, which can be concatenated with another string in the template.

Comment: so any idea why it might not work??

Comment: What happens when you use the tag. Post the traceback error. Do you have the correct path in your` urlconf`?

Comment: when i did from django.conf.urls.defaults import * i got no module error

Comment: when i deleted it it says url not defined in url(r'^$', 'index', name='index'),

Comment: which is in views.py

Answer (score 0):

From what you have posted above, it seems like django cannot find a relevent path in urlconf.

You can have:

**urls.py**

```
    ...
    (r'^$', 'index', name='index'),
    (r'^articles$', 'articles', name='articles')
    ...
```

Then in your template:

```html
href="/articles"
```

or

```
href="{% url 'articles' %}"
```

Your `index` path can only work for empty path, hence reversing it in the template does not make sense because the reversed url is simply an empty string.

If you want index and articles  paths to be handled by the same view i.e `index`, you can have:

**urls.py**

```
    ...
    (r'^$', 'index', name='index'),
    (r'^articles$', 'index', name='articles')
    ...
```